# $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\dfrac{n^{2}-n+2}{3n^{2}+2n-4}=\dfrac{1}{3}.$ Change $n$'s by $x$ and find $M$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^2-n+2}{3n^2+2n-4}=\dfrac{1}{3}$.

With epsilon definition I get my answer as $N=\left[ \dfrac{5}{9\varepsilon }\right] +1$. But then I thought that how can I evaluate this sequence, in functions $\delta$-$\varepsilon$ definition by substituting $n$ by $x$. But I can't make it.

So here's my question:

What can I do is I have function like this one?
$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{x^2-x+2}{3x^2+2x-4}=\dfrac{1}{3}$.

I'm thinking about that function. But how to find.

$\forall \varepsilon>0$ be given, then $\exists M>0$ such that $x>M$ implies $| f\left( x\right) -l|<\varepsilon$

For function:
$\left| \dfrac{x^{2}-x+2}{3x^{2}+2x-4}-\dfrac{1}{3}\right|=
\left| \dfrac{-5x+10}{9x^{2}+6x-12}\right|<\left| \dfrac{-5x+10}{9x^{2}}\right|$

And this is where I stuck. Because $x\in \mathbb{R}$, so I think we can't remove the brackets. Isn't it?
For y'all's helps I solved it thank you all!

Comment: When $n$ gets very large, the $n^2$ terms dominate

Comment: Can you make your question more clear ?

Comment: Yes, I know but I can't reduce the inequality for $\delta-\epsilon$

Comment: Okay I'll edit.

Comment: You don't _evaluate_ anything by the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition, but _prove_ the limit is indeed $\frac13$.

Comment: Yes I meant this

Comment: I think you should write what you've done by the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition and clarify what you are confused about.

Comment: I will edit for that too

Comment: Your new edit says you're stuck because you think we can't remove the brackets, but $9x^2+6$ is always positive, and, for large enough $x$, $|-5x+10|=5x-10$

Comment: So if I do those I get: $\dfrac{5}{9x}$. Isn't it?

Comment: As $x\to-\infty, |9x^2+6x-12|<|9x^2+6|$, that is something that you would need to change for $x<0$.

Comment: Is it okay now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to prove that

$\forall\;\varepsilon>0\;\;\exists\;M>0\;$ such that $\;x>M\;$ implies $\;\left|f\left(x\right)-l\right|<\varepsilon\;.$

For any $\;\varepsilon>0\;,\;$ let $\;M=\max\left\{2,\dfrac{5}{9\varepsilon}\right\}>0\;.$

Moreover,

$x>M\ge2\implies|-5x+10|=5x-10<5x\;,$

$x>M\ge2\implies|9x^2+6x-12|=9x^2+6x-12>9x^2\;.$

Hence,

$x>M\implies\left| \dfrac{-5x+10}{9x^{2}+6x-12}\right|<\dfrac{5x}{9x^2}=\dfrac{5}{9x}\;.$

Consequently,

$x>M\implies|f(x)-l|=\left|\dfrac{x^{2}-x+2}{3x^{2}+2x-4}-\dfrac{1}{3}\right|=\left| \dfrac{-5x+10}{9x^{2}+6x-12}\right|<\dfrac{5}{9x}<\dfrac{5}{9M}\le\dfrac{5}{9\frac{5}{9\varepsilon}}=\varepsilon\;.$

Comment: Thank you! That's what I found in the end!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

If you use the long division, you have
$$\frac{n^{2}-n+2}{3n^{2}+2n-4}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{5}{9 n}+\frac{40}{27
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Therefore
$$ \frac{1}{3}-\frac{5}{9 n}<\frac{n^{2}-n+2}{3n^{2}+2n-4}<\frac{1}{3}-\frac{5}{9 n}+\frac{40}{27
   n^2}$$

Comment: What did you use? Polynomial Division?

Comment: @beingmathematician. Yes (this is what I call long division).

Comment: Okay thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

How is it any different from what you've already done? Renaming $n$ into $x$ and $N$ into $M$ doesn't really change anything. The same answer still works. Or you can simplify it a little by dropping the rounding, since $M$ doesn't have to be an integer anymore.

Comment: But in the functions "infinity to number" definition we have &x>M& so it changes. Isn't it?

Comment: @beingmathematician: And in the $\varepsilon$-$N$ definition of limits of sequences we have $n>N$. So after renaming it's the same thing.

Comment: So how can I write it? I can't make it, I'm confused at all. I mean M equal what

Comment: @beingmathematician: My point is that this is going to be exactly the same solution. The only thing you need to do is renaming. In particular, your $M$ can be precisely the same thing as your $N$ -- it will work, because it will satisfy the definition. But if we want to simplify it a bit, considering $M$ doesn't have to be an integer anymore, we can drop the brackets for rounding and "$+1$"  -- that will work too.

Comment: I clearly understand what you meant. I'll try to do that, but because we don't working on N anymore, I can't reduce the x's. I'll write it too. However, thanks a lot